# how can i make the background image fixed

Tags: css, background-image

The size of the picture is 5834*3886
I wrote the code as shown but when I minimize the browser the picture size just change and part of it disappear , I want it to be fixed is there a way ?

```
.contact{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 50px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: url(pic.jpg);
    background-size: cover;    
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position

Answer (score 1):

As per the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) documentation.

```
Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges
```

It means the image will be spread in the div in a way that no edges will be left behind. And it will shrink based on the window size.

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://assets.dragoart.com/images/11939_501/how-to-draw-iron-man-easy_5e4c9ed9b16b58.14188289_53732_3_3.png');
}

.item1 {
  background-size: cover;
}

.item2 {
  background-size: contain;
}

.item3 {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item item1">
</div>
<div class="item item2">
</div>
<div class="item item3">
</div>
```

As you can see in the above snippet,

First item is `background-size: cover`;

Which means either width or height will be 100% in a way that `there won't be any space left behind in the container even the other value overflows`. This will keep the images original ratio of resolution.

Second item is `background-size: contain`;

Which means either height or width will be 100% in a way that, `there won't be overflow,` instead `there will be space left behind` in the container. This will keep the images original ratio of resolution.

Third item is `background-size: 100% 100%`;

Which means the width and height will be 100% in a way that there `won't be any space left behind and there won't be any overflow`. This will **not** keep the images original ratio of resolution.

Hope this would clarify your doubt.

Comment: by resizing u mean I give it new width and height, right? I tried doing so and it looked really bad

Comment: Nop, by resizing I mean if you resize the screen width, the image width and height will also get updated accordingly

Comment: ok thank you so much i will try looking into it

Comment: i understand what is written but i can't understand what is supposed to be labeled item1 and item2 in my code

Comment: If you are planning to keep your image fixed height and width, specify it in background-size, so it won't change when screen size changes. And if you want it to be responsive to the screen changes, keep it cover, contain or in % as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```css
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: I can update my full code. Please see the css. now working well..

Answer (score 1):

**You need something like this**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #ex {
            text-align: center;
            background-image:
url("https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png");
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
      
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Example for fixed Background Image</h1>

    <div id="ex">
        
<p>
            Paragraphs are the building blocks
            of papers. Many students define
            paragraphs in terms of length: a
            paragraph is a group of at least
            five sentences,
        </p>

        <br><br>

        
<p>
            a paragraph is half a page long,
            etc. In reality, though, the unity
            and coherence of ideas among
            sentences is what constitutes a
            paragraph.
        </p>

        <br><br>

        
<p>
            A paragraph is defined as “a group
            of sentences or a single sentence
            that forms a unit” (Lunsford and
            Connors 116).
        </p>


        <br><br>
        
<p>
            Length and appearance do not
            determine whether a section in
            a paper is a paragraph.
        </p>

        <br><br>

        
<p>
            For instance, in some styles of
            writing, particularly journalistic
            styles, a paragraph can be just
            one sentence long. Ultimately, a
            paragraph is a sentence or group of
            sentences that support one main idea.
        </p>

        <br><br>

        
<p>
            In this handout, we will refer to this
            as the “controlling idea,” because it
            controls what happens in the rest
            of the paragraph.
        </p>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Let me know if this will work for you.**

Comment: I tried doing the same CSS code and it didn't work for me for some reason even though your code runs perfectly with your image

Answer (score 1):

Please see this code...

```css
.contact{
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100vh;
        padding: 50px 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: url(https://data.1freewallpapers.com/detail/calm-body-of-water-surrounded-with-trees-and-mountains-during-daytime-4k-nature.jpg);
        background-size: cover;    
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Images</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<section>
    <div class="contact">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </h1>

         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </h1>


         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </h1>


         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </h1>


         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </h1>

         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and the background image isn't fixed its size changed by minimizing and maximizing.

Comment: In here i can see The background is fixed. Click the button here "Run code snippet". see all are ok. Maybe in your code have another problem.